# Oracle SQL calculate average/opening/closing balances from discrete data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have account balances like this

```
acc_no      balance  balance_date
account1    5000     2020-01-01
account1    6000     2020-01-05
account2    3000     2020-01-01
account1    3500     2020-01-08
account2    7500     2020-01-15
```

the effective balance for any day without a balance entry is equal to to the last balance. eg account1 balance on 2,3,4 Jan is 5000 etc.

I would like to produce the daily average, opening and closing balance from this data for any period. I came up with the following query and it works but it takes half an hour when I run it against the full data set. Is my approach correct or there is a more efficient method?

```
WITH cte_period
AS (
    SELECT '2020-01-01' date_from
        ,'2020-01-31' date_to
    FROM dual
    )
    ,cte_calendar
AS (
    SELECT rownum
        ,(
            SELECT to_date(date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            FROM cte_period
            ) + rownum - 1 AS balance_day
    FROM dual connect BY rownum <= (
            SELECT to_date(date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            FROM cte_period
            ) - (
            SELECT to_date(date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            FROM cte_period
            ) + 1
    )
    ,cte_balances
AS (
    SELECT 'account1' acc_no
        ,5000 balance
        ,to_date('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') sys_date
    FROM dual

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'account1'
        ,6000
        ,to_date('2020-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    FROM dual

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'account2'
        ,3000
        ,to_date('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    FROM dual

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'account1'
        ,3500
        ,to_date('2020-01-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    FROM dual

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'account2'
        ,7500
        ,to_date('2020-01-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    FROM dual
    )
    ,cte_accounts
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT acc_no
    FROM cte_balances
    )
SELECT t.acc_no
    ,(
        SELECT eff_bal
        FROM (
            SELECT cal.balance_day
                ,acc_nos.acc_no
                ,(
                    SELECT balance
                    FROM cte_balances bal
                    WHERE bal.sys_date <= cal.balance_day
                        AND acc_nos.acc_no = bal.acc_no
                    ORDER BY bal.sys_date DESC FETCH first 1 row ONLY
                    ) eff_bal
            FROM cte_calendar cal
            CROSS JOIN cte_accounts acc_nos
            ) t1
        WHERE balance_day = (
                SELECT to_date(date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                FROM cte_period
                )
            AND t.acc_no = t1.acc_no
        ) opening_bal
    ,(
        SELECT eff_bal
        FROM (
            SELECT cal.balance_day
                ,acc_nos.acc_no
                ,(
                    SELECT balance
                    FROM cte_balances bal
                    WHERE bal.sys_date <= cal.balance_day
                        AND acc_nos.acc_no = bal.acc_no
                    ORDER BY bal.sys_date DESC FETCH first 1 row ONLY
                    ) eff_bal
            FROM cte_calendar cal
            CROSS JOIN cte_accounts acc_nos
            ) t1
        WHERE balance_day = (
                SELECT to_date(date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                FROM cte_period
                )
            AND t.acc_no = t1.acc_no
        ) closing_bal
    ,round(avg(eff_bal), 2) avg_bal
FROM (
    SELECT cal.balance_day
        ,acc_nos.acc_no
        ,(
            SELECT balance
            FROM cte_balances bal
            WHERE bal.sys_date <= cal.balance_day
                AND acc_nos.acc_no = bal.acc_no
            ORDER BY bal.sys_date DESC FETCH first 1 row ONLY
            ) eff_bal
    FROM cte_calendar cal
    CROSS JOIN cte_accounts acc_nos
    ) t
GROUP BY acc_no
order by acc_no
```

The expected result
    ACC_NO      OPENING_BAL CLOSING_BAL   AVG_BAL
    account1    5000         3500         3935.48
    account2    3000         7500         5467.74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are unnecesary selecting from same table many times. Produce calendar as you did, join with your data partitioned by account and use analytic functions for computations:

```
select acc_no, round(avg(bal), 2) av_bal,
       max(bal) keep (dense_rank first order by day) op_bal, 
       max(bal) keep (dense_rank last order by day) cl_bal
  from (
    select acc_no, day, 
           nvl(balance, lag(balance) ignore nulls over (partition by acc_no order by day)) bal
      from (
        select date_from + level - 1 as day
          from (select date '2020-01-01' date_from, date '2020-01-31' date_to from dual)
          connect by date_from + level - 1 <= date_to)
      left join cte_balances partition by (acc_no) on day = sys_date)
  group by acc_no
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a56054e90aa228fbbf7f2bd5fec38648)</sup>**

**Edit:**

> sometimes the first day of the month has no balance entry, it should
>   take form the last available

We have to treat first row in special way. It's done in subquery `data`, where in case of first row and null balance I run correlated subquery which looks for balance from max previous date.

```
with 
  cte_calendar as (
    select level lvl, date_from + level - 1 as day
      from (select date '2020-01-01' date_from, date '2020-01-31' date_to from dual)
      connect by date_from + level - 1 <= date_to),
  data as (
    select lvl, day, acc_no, 
           case when balance is null and lvl = 1 
                then (select max(balance) keep (dense_rank last order by sys_date) 
                        from cte_balances a
                        where a.acc_no = b.acc_no and a.sys_date <= day) 
                else balance
           end bal
      from cte_calendar
      left join cte_balances b partition by (acc_no) on day = sys_date)
select acc_no, 
       max(bal) keep (dense_rank first order by day) op_bal, 
       max(bal) keep (dense_rank last order by day) cl_bal, 
       round(avg(bal), 2)
  from (
    select acc_no, day, 
           nvl(bal, lag(bal) ignore nulls over (partition by acc_no order by day)) bal
      from data)
  group by acc_no
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=987994649eccbfcae221a3cc8a547f4b)</sup>**

> although I don't understand it yet

There are thre things, which are not obvoius here and you should know to understand query:

- partitioned outer join. It's main part of the solution which produces whole period for each account. You can read about them [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) for instance,
- `lag() ignore nulls` - fills null balance values, take them from previous not null,
- `max(bal) keep (dense_rank first order by day)` takes balance value from first date for opening balance. `last` - from last row for closing balance.

Comment: I put the dates at the top to be easier to edit the query. I ran your code it produces the expected results although I don't understand it yet. Will accept the answer and read about analytics functions.

Comment: There is a problem, sometimes the first day of the month has no balance entry, it should take form the last available. Your solution does not apply for values outside the range.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford using `first_value`, `last_value` analytic functions, then this, based on my understanding of your description, may help:

> ```
> with data as (
>  select           'account1' as acc, 5000 as balance, to_date('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d from dual
>  union all select 'account1' as acc, 6000 as balance, to_date('2020-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d from dual
>  union all select 'account2' as acc, 3000 as balance, to_date('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d from dual
>  union all select 'account1' as acc, 3500 as balance, to_date('2020-01-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d from dual
>  union all select 'account1' as acc, 7500 as balance, to_date('2020-01-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d from dual
> )
>
> select acc, avg(balance) over (partition by acc order by balance) as average, 
>         first_value(balance) over(partition by acc order by balance asc rows unbounded preceding) as first, 
>         last_value(balance) over(partition by acc order by balance asc rows unbounded preceding) as last
> from data
> where d between to_date('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2020-01-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
> order by acc
> ```
>
> ```
> ACC      | AVERAGE | FIRST | LAST
> :------- | ------: | ----: | ---:
> account1 |    5000 |  5000 | 5000
> account1 |    5500 |  5000 | 6000
> account2 |    3000 |  3000 | 3000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=84e3580ac745c3212d0a9dc05feac9c0)*

Comment: the averages are not correct. i need a daily average not the average of existing values.

Comment: @Patriot Maybe I've lost something, but isn't `1 + 1 / 2 == 1` ?

Comment: like i mentioned in the question, the daily average for a month has to account for missing days and take the last known balance. ie. on 2,3,4 jan the balance is 5000 for account 1. so a monthly average should fill in missing days and take them into consideration.